# Pandas series between two date time files

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, data-science

My question is about using Pandas time series.

I have one file(Spots) that has pandas time series for a month's data with 7.5 seconds range.
Example :

```
2016-11-01 00:00:00,0
2016-11-01 00:00:07.500000,1
2016-11-01 00:00:15,2
2016-11-01 00:00:22.500000,3
2016-11-01 00:00:30,4
```

The other file(Target) has just time information .

Example:

```
2016-11-01 00:00:05
2016-11-01 00:00:07
2016-11-01 00:00:23
2016-11-01 00:00:25
```

I want to check which spot does the target date time belong to:
Output in above example :

```
2016-11-01 00:00:00,0 '\t' count of targets in this spot = 2
2016-11-01 00:00:07.500000,1 '\t' count of targets in this spot = 0
2016-11-01 00:00:15,2 '\t' count of targets in this spot = 0
2016-11-01 00:00:22.500000,3 '\t' count of targets in this spot = 0
2016-11-01 00:00:30,4 '\t' count of targets in this spot = 2
```

Thank you so much in advance. Kinda let me know if this is clear otherwise I can try to explain more.

Comment: How does the first row have 2 targets in that spot?  It looks like it should be 0.  Unless you're rounding down the Target to the closest Spot?  A little more clarity on the logic behind the result would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use `merge_ordered`, `fillna`, and `groupby`:

Inputs:

```
df_spots

                     Date  Value
0 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000      0
1 2016-11-01 00:00:07.500      1
2 2016-11-01 00:00:15.000      2
3 2016-11-01 00:00:22.500      3
4 2016-11-01 00:00:30.000      4

df_target

                 Date
0 2016-11-01 00:00:05
1 2016-11-01 00:00:07
2 2016-11-01 00:00:23
3 2016-11-01 00:00:25
```

Code:

```
merged_df = pd.merge_ordered(df_spots, df_target, on = 'Date')
df_out = (merged_df.groupby(by=merged_df['Value']
               .fillna(method='ffill'), as_index=False)
               .agg({'Date':'first',
                     'Value':{'first':'first','count':lambda x:len(x)-1}}))
```

Outputs:

```
df_out

                     Date Value      
                    first first count
0 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000   0.0   2.0
1 2016-11-01 00:00:07.500   1.0   0.0
2 2016-11-01 00:00:15.000   2.0   0.0
3 2016-11-01 00:00:22.500   3.0   2.0
4 2016-11-01 00:00:30.000   4.0   0.0
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you all so much! I din't know of so many nice and elegant ways to use Panda for this. I will try all of these tonight and let you all know how it goes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Scott Boston, I tried your method but I am not getting the counts rather it is just matching the first column which I think is the row number?. First , I had to change merge_ordered to order_merged but even then I am getting the same. I noticed that in the merged_df there is no 'value' in the second data frame and so would the groupie on 'value' still work? Can you help me understand what I might be doing wrong?. Also when I print my df_out, I get first count first instead of first first count.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?  I am on the latest 0.19.2, I think you might be on an early version.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that and upgraded pandas and ran it and it worked beautifully. Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion. First, add another column to the target frame. This will make it possible to recognize the targets after a future merge:

```
target['T'] = 1
```

Concatenate the targets and the spots and sort them by the time:

```
both = pd.concat([spots,target]).sort_values(0)
#                        0    1    T
#0 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0.0  NaN
#0 2016-11-01 00:00:05.000  NaN  1.0
#1 2016-11-01 00:00:07.000  NaN  1.0
#1 2016-11-01 00:00:07.500  1.0  NaN
#2 2016-11-01 00:00:15.000  2.0  NaN
#3 2016-11-01 00:00:22.500  3.0  NaN
#2 2016-11-01 00:00:23.000  NaN  1.0
#3 2016-11-01 00:00:25.000  NaN  1.0
#4 2016-11-01 00:00:30.000  4.0  NaN
```

Forward-fill the spot IDs:

```
both[1] = both[1].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
#                        0  1    T
#0 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0  NaN
#0 2016-11-01 00:00:05.000  0  1.0
#1 2016-11-01 00:00:07.000  0  1.0
#1 2016-11-01 00:00:07.500  1  NaN
#2 2016-11-01 00:00:15.000  2  NaN
#3 2016-11-01 00:00:22.500  3  NaN
#2 2016-11-01 00:00:23.000  3  1.0
#3 2016-11-01 00:00:25.000  3  1.0
#4 2016-11-01 00:00:30.000  4  NaN
```

Select the original target rows and columns:

```
both[both['T']==1][[0,1]]
#                    0  1
#0 2016-11-01 00:00:05  0
#1 2016-11-01 00:00:07  0
#2 2016-11-01 00:00:23  3
#3 2016-11-01 00:00:25  3
```

If you want to count targets in spots, use `groupby()`:

```
both.groupby(1).count()['T']
#1
#0    2
#1    0
#2    0
#3    2
#4    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `np.searchsorted` and `pd.value_counts` plus some other stuff.

```
idx = Spots.index.to_series()
i = idx.values
t = Target.Date.values
m = pd.value_counts(i[i.searchsorted(t) - 1]).to_dict()
Spots.assign(TargetCount=idx.map(lambda x: m.get(x, 0)))

                         Value  TargetCount
Date                                       
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000      0            2
2016-11-01 00:00:07.500      1            0
2016-11-01 00:00:15.000      2            0
2016-11-01 00:00:22.500      3            2
2016-11-01 00:00:30.000      4            0
```

***How It Works***

- `idx` is the index of `Spots` turned to a `pd.Series` because I want to use `pd.Series.map` later.
- `i` is the underlying `numpy` array that I'll perform a `searchsorted` operation with
- `t` same as `i`... part of the `searchsorted`
- `searchsorted` will go through each element in the right array and find the position in which that element should be inserted with respect to the right array.  This information can be used to find the "bin" the elements belong to.  I then subtract one to align with the appropriate indices
- I then perform a `pd.value_counts` to count them
- Use `map` to build a new column.

---

***Setup***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

tx1 = """2016-11-01 00:00:00,0
2016-11-01 00:00:07.500000,1
2016-11-01 00:00:15,2
2016-11-01 00:00:22.500000,3
2016-11-01 00:00:30,4"""

tx2 = """2016-11-01 00:00:05
2016-11-01 00:00:07
2016-11-01 00:00:23
2016-11-01 00:00:25"""

Spots = pd.read_csv(StringIO(tx1), parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, names=['Date', 'Value'])

Target = pd.read_csv(StringIO(tx2), parse_dates=[0], names=['Date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas **merge_asof**
(note, all time values must be ordered - may have to sort first):

Setup ~~~~~~~~

```
import pandas as pd    

# make date_range with 1 sec interval (fake targets)
rng = pd.date_range('2016-11-01', periods=100, freq='S')

# resample to make 7.5 sec intervals (fake spot bins)
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(100), index=rng)
ts_vals = ts.resample('7500L').asfreq().index

df_spots = pd.DataFrame({'spot': np.arange(len(ts_vals)), 'bin': ts_vals})
df_spots.head()
                      bin  spot
0 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
1 2016-11-01 00:00:07.500  1   
2 2016-11-01 00:00:15.000  2   
3 2016-11-01 00:00:22.500  3   
4 2016-11-01 00:00:30.000  4 

df_targets = pd.DataFrame(rng, columns=['tgt'])
df_targets.head()

                  tgt
0 2016-11-01 00:00:00
1 2016-11-01 00:00:01
2 2016-11-01 00:00:02
3 2016-11-01 00:00:03
4 2016-11-01 00:00:04
```

Solution ~~~~~~~

```
# this will produce spot membership for targets
df = pd.merge_asof(df_targets, df_spots, left_on='tgt', right_on='bin')
df.head()
                  tgt                     bin  spot
0 2016-11-01 00:00:00 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
1 2016-11-01 00:00:01 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
2 2016-11-01 00:00:02 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
3 2016-11-01 00:00:03 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
4 2016-11-01 00:00:04 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
5 2016-11-01 00:00:05 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
6 2016-11-01 00:00:06 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
7 2016-11-01 00:00:07 2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  0   
8 2016-11-01 00:00:08 2016-11-01 00:00:07.500  1   
9 2016-11-01 00:00:09 2016-11-01 00:00:07.500  1   

# for spot counts...
df_counts = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('bin')['spot'].count())
df_counts.head()
                         spot
bin                          
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000  8   
2016-11-01 00:00:07.500  7   
2016-11-01 00:00:15.000  8   
2016-11-01 00:00:22.500  7   
2016-11-01 00:00:30.000  8
```